# Rails ActiveRecord - vaildate uniqueness with named scope (not the scope like other columns)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Imagine a Users table:

| id | email | access_token | refresh_token | country_id | city_id | discarded_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | james.dean@example.com | 11111 | 22222 | 1 | 1 | 2021-01-31 00:57:25 |
| 2 | james.bond@example.com | 33333 | 44444 | 1 | 3 | NULL |
| 3 | james.franco@example.com | 55555 | 66666 | 2 | 4 | NULL |
| 4 | james.corden@example.com | 77777 | 88888 | 1 | 5 | NULL |
| 5 | james.dean@example.com | 11111 | 22222 | 1 | 1 | NULL |

Usually, validating uniqueness of other columns is like this

```
validates :emails, :access_token, :refresh_token, uniqueness: { scope: %i[country_id city_id] }
```

Now the question is - how to do it for a named scope?

Say for example, there's a named scope `scope :kept, -> { where(discarded_at: nil) }`, then `email`, `access_token` and `refresh_token` should be unique for all the `kept` users.

(With the example above, i.e. ID=5 is valid because ID=1 is already discarded, so email, access_token and refresh_token of ID=5 are valid)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :kept, -> { where(discarded_at: nil) }

   # maybe something like this?
  validates :email, :access_token, :refresh_token, uniqueness: { where(discarded_at: nil) }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `conditions` option (as outlined [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of))

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :access_token, :refresh_token, conditions: -> { where(discarded_at: nil) }
```

Comment: Yup, that is the correct approach but is important to mention that you can run into race conditions, so if you really want to validate uniqueness you will need to add an index in your DB as well. (since the validations are only on application-level you may run into race conditions, even if the odds are not big you should definitely add that index) 

Answer (score 1):

Just to further expand @AbM's answer together with @r4cc00n's comment.

Here's the complete answer:

- with the new `validates` syntax
- it needs to `allow_nil`
- add DB level index

**Model**

```
validates :email, :access_token, :refresh_token,
          uniqueness: { allow_nil: true, conditions: -> { where(discarded_at: nil) } }
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateUniqueIndiceToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true, where: "(discarded_at IS NULL)"
    add_index :users, :access_token, unique: true, where: "(discarded_at IS NULL)"
    add_index :users, :refresh_token, unique: true, where: "(discarded_at IS NULL)"
  end
end
```